# How to create button like this in android studio?

Tags: android, button

So I have a question.

How is it possible to create a Button like this?
In this example this button is always visible and when the user clicks it goes to the home button. It's not important how the code brings the user to the homescreen. Only this visible button!

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this and set its background/src accordingly.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library, it will create the always floating button:

https://github.com/recruit-lifestyle/FloatingView